# React Native map axios instead of a imported file

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios

I am studying React Native, and I forked this [Github Repository](https://github.com/Trancever/twitterClone) and I have a [feed.tsx](https://github.com/Trancever/twitterClone/blob/master/src/feed.tsx) that returns a FlatList and it renders a function that map the variable **twitts**. I want to try to use Axios instead of data imported file as the following code:

```
  feed.tsx

  import React from 'react';
  import {FlatList, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
  import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
  import {useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
  import axios from 'axios';

  import {Twitt} from './components/twitt';
  import {twitts} from './data';
  import {StackNavigatorParamlist} from './types';

  type TwittProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Twitt>;

  function renderItem({item}: { item: TwittProps }) {
      return <Twitt {...item} />;
  }

  function keyExtractor(item: TwittProps) {
      return item.id.toString();
  }

  type Props = {
      navigation?: StackNavigationProp<StackNavigatorParamlist>;
  };

  export const Feed = (props: Props) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      var response = axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=49f0f29739e21ecda580cd926a19075e&language=en-US&page=1');
      const data = response.data.result.map(twittProps => ({
          ...twittProps,
          onPress: () =>
              props.navigation &&
              props.navigation.push('Details', {
                  ...twittProps,
              }),
      }));
      return (
          <FlatList
              contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}}
              style={{backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}}
              data={data}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                  <View style={{height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth}}/>
              )}
          />
      );
  };
```

And the following twitt.tsx:

```
      import React from 'react';
  import {StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
  import {
      Surface,
      Title,
      Caption,
      Text,
      Avatar,
      TouchableRipple,
      useTheme,
  } from 'react-native-paper';
  import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
  import color from 'color';
  
  type Props = {
      id: number;
      adult: boolean,
      popularity: number,
      vote_count: number,
      video: boolean,
      poster_path: string,
      backdrop_path: string,
      original_language: string,
      original_title: string,
      genre_ids: any,
      title: string,
      vote_average: number,
      overview: string,
      release_date: string,
      onPress: (id: number) => void;
  };
  
  export const Twitt = (props: Props) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
  
      const iconColor = color(theme.colors.text)
          .alpha(0.54)
          .rgb()
          .string();
  
      const contentColor = color(theme.colors.text)
          .alpha(0.8)
          .rgb()
          .string();
  
      const imageBorderColor = color(theme.colors.text)
          .alpha(0.15)
          .rgb()
          .string();
  
      return (
          <TouchableRipple onPress={() => props.onPress(props.id)}>
              <Surface style={styles.container}>
                  <View style={styles.leftColumn}>
                      <Image style={styles.movieImg} source={{uri: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" +props.backdrop_path }}/>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.rightColumn}>
                      <View style={styles.topRow}>
                          <Title>{props.title}</Title>
                          <Caption style={[styles.handle, styles.dot]}>{'\u2B24'}</Caption>
                      </View>
                      <Text style={{color: contentColor}}>{props.overview}</Text>
                      <View style={styles.bottomRow}>
                          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                  name="star-circle"
                                  size={20}
                                  color={iconColor}
                              />
                              <Caption style={styles.iconDescription}>
                                  {props.vote_average}
                              </Caption>
                          </View>
                          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                  name="thumb-up-outline"
                                  size={20}
                                  color={iconColor}
                              />
                              <Caption style={styles.iconDescription}>
                                  {props.popularity}
                              </Caption>
                          </View>
                          <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                  name="calendar"
                                  size={20}
                                  color={iconColor}
                              />
                              <Caption style={styles.iconDescription}>{props.release_date}</Caption>
                          </View>
                      </View>
                  </View>
              </Surface>
          </TouchableRipple>
      );
  };
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingTop: 15,
          paddingRight: 15,
      },
      leftColumn: {
          width: 100,
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 10
      },
      rightColumn: {
          flex: 1,
      },
      topRow: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'baseline',
      },
      handle: {
          marginRight: 3,
      },
      dot: {
          fontSize: 3,
      },
      image: {
          borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
          marginTop: 10,
          borderRadius: 20,
          width: '100%',
          height: 150,
      },
      bottomRow: {
          paddingVertical: 10,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
      },
      iconContainer: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
      },
      iconDescription: {
          marginLeft: 2,
          lineHeight: 20,
          fontSize: 15
      },
      movieImg: {
          width: "100%",
          height: 100,
      }
  });
```

But, when I map Axios response data it doesn't work:
[image: The same code showing error]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Why do you need `setState()` inside `feed.tsx`? And what you mean by "set twitts var as axios response"? Sorry, for me it's unclear what you are trying to do...

Comment: You mean instead of importing `twitts` from `./data` you want to use an API response? So you would do your `map` in that response, right? Usually, a common mistake is to get the response from Axios and try to loop the promise, instead of waiting for the API call to resolve. Did you try anything yet (do you have any code with the Axios call?) or just asking in general?

Comment: Yes, I want to use API istead of ./data. But, I used console.log(response.data.results) and is working!  I thought the problem was the type, but it wasn't!

Comment: Cool. So you can use `response.data.results.map(...` and you should be fine. Just update your question if you need help with anything else. Also, if you find your solution you should answer your own question to leave as a reference for future users.

Comment: Well, I've tried it all the day without success.

Comment: Maybe update your question then with your current code that is not working, and include any error messages (if you have any from the console or something). I mean, if `console.log` works, it means that you were able to get the response from your API. Can you include that as well? Maybe your `data.results` is not an array? Hard to say without much more info :)

Comment: I've changed the question. Maybe now is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. The issue is that `axios.get()`[returns a promise](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage), not the data itself. So you just need to `await` ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)) for that promise. So your function should be like this:

```
export const Feed = async(props: Props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    var response = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=49f0f29739e21ecda580cd926a19075e&language=en-US&page=1');
    // rest of your code...
```

Note the `async` keyword before the function props, which is required when using `await`.

Another option is to use the old approach with `then`, but that makes your code less readable. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: Hello, on yesterday I discovered that was the promise. Thanks bro! But, it still returns an error:
Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary

Comment: Hmm that's a default React message saying that you had an error that was not captured. But is just a `warning` so it shouldn't stop your components. Did the map work or is this `warning` preventing your code to work? Does it tell you which line the error happened?